# CSS flex-direction: row-reverse Ruins wrapping

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

so basically I have this form which is the Benin flag as you can see.

What i want to achieve is the exact same copy but mirrored, the green on the right with yellow on top of blue, but when i use reverse-row, the red falls off under the green instead.

[here is the normal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB0xs.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOxy1.png)

Here is the code:

```
.flag{
   position:relative;
   display:flex;
   flex-flow:column wrap;
   width:200px;
   height:150px;
   border:2px solid black;
}

>! flex-direction= row-reverse;

.green{background:green;}
.yellow{background:yellow;}
.red{background:red;}

.col1{width:40%;height:100%;}
.col2{width:60%;height:50%;}
```

```
<div class=flag>
 <div class='col1 green'></div>
 <div class='col2 yellow'></div>
 <div class='col2 red'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What `row-reverse` does in your example is it changes `flex-direction` from `column` to `row-reverse`, so it's no surprise that it's no longer in a column flow.

Use `wrap-reverse` instead, to reverse the column wrapping direction:

```css
.flag {
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column wrap-reverse;
   width: 200px;
   height: 150px;
   border: 2px solid black;
}

.green {background: green;}
.yellow {background: yellow;}
.red {background: red;}

.col1 {width: 40%; height: 100%;}
.col2 {width: 60%; height: 50%;}
```

```html
<div class='flag'>
 <div class='col1 green'></div>
 <div class='col2 yellow'></div>
 <div class='col2 red'></div>
</div>
```